# Why is dart wrongly inferring my generic parameter type?

Tags: variables, generics, dart, types, collections

I can't seem to understand why the mySet variable is being inferred as a generic set with dynamic parameter type, when I clearly equated it to an int set literal. So is this result logical or has dart genuinely failed to infer the generic sets parameter type?

```
main(){
  Set mySet = {1 ,2 , 3};
  var myProducts = {
    1:'TV',2:'Refrigerator',
    3:mySet.lookup(2),
    4:'Tablet',
    5:'Computer'
    };
    var userCollection = {"name":"John Smith","Email":"john@sanjib.site"};
    myProducts.forEach((x,y) => print("${x} : ${y}"));
    userCollection.forEach((k, v) => print("${k} : ${v}"));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare a variable with a generic type `Generic` but omit the parameterized type, it's (usually<sup>1</sup>) shorthand for `Generic<dynamic>`.  Inference does happen in your assignment, but *not in the direction you expect*: since you explicitly declared the type of `mySet`, the type of `{1, 2, 3}` is inferred from that explicit type (`Set`/`Set<dynamic>`) and becomes `<dynamic>{1, 2, 3}` instead of `<int>{1, 2, 3}`.

This is one reason why it can be better to omit explicit types and just allow types to be inferred when possible.  Using:

```dart
var mySet = {1, 2, 3};
```

would allow `mySet` to be inferred as `Set<int>`.  If you really want to use explicit types, you should ensure that you specify explicit types for generic type parameters too.

You can catch such errors by setting:

```yaml
analyzer:
  language:
    strict-raw-types: true
```

in your `analysis_options.yaml` file. (You also might wish to enable:

```yaml
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

too.)

Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/resources/type-system/strict-raw-types.md:

> ```dart
> void main() {
>   List a = [1, 2, 3];
> }
> ```
>
> Developers often think that inference fills in the type of `a` from the right side of the assignment. It may look like `a` has the type `List<int>`. But Dart fills in omitted type arguments, like `E` on `List`, with `dynamic` (or the corresponding type parameter's bound); `List a;` is purely a shorthand for `List<dynamic> a;`. Inference then flows from `a` onto the expression on the right side of the assignment.

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, if a generic's type parameter is constrained (e.g. `class Generic<T extends Base>`), then omitting the type parameter is shorthand for using that constraint (i.e., `Generic` would be shorthand for `Generic<Base>`).  Most generics don't constraint their type parameters, so therefore it usually ends up being `dynamic`.

Comment: So an inference wasn't really made in this situation as by default the parameter type is given as dynamic if I omitted a parameter type?

Comment: @vecohah Inference was done in that the right-hand-side was inferred from the left-hand-side, which is the opposite direction from what you want.

Comment: So the right hand side defaulted by omission to a dynamic parameter type therefore the right hand side was inferred as a set of parameter type dynamic?

Comment: @vecohah Normally the RHS by itself would be inferred to be `<int>{1, 2, 3}`, but because the LHS explicitly specified a type (`Set`, which is equivalent to `Set<dynamic>`), the RHS was adjusted to match the left.  If you declared your variable with `var` or `final`, then your variable would have been inferred to be `Set<int>`.