# Dart initialise a list in a Map using putIfAbsent

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a map of lists e.g.

```
HashMap exampleMap = new HashMap<String, List<Foo>>();
```

I want to initialise a new list if the key does not exist, I've been trying variations of putIfAbsent but have had no success so far

```
exampleMap.putIfAbsent('bar', () => []);
```

My ultimate goal is to add items to the list but the list needs to be initialised first

```
exampleMap['bar'].add(fooItem);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong:

> ```dart
> HashMap exampleMap = new HashMap<String, List<Foo>>();
> ```

This declares `exampleMap` to be a `HashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`. (See [Why is dart wrongly inferring my generic parameter type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61805709/) for an explanation why.)

The moral is: if you want to declare types explicitly, you *must* be explicit *everywhere*.  You can't take half-measures.  Otherwise just use `var` and allow the type of the variable to be inferred from the right-hand-side.

Later when you do:

> ```dart
> exampleMap.putIfAbsent('bar', () => []);
> ```

Because `exampleMap`'s static (known at compile-time) type is `HashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`, nothing is known about the type for the `HashMap`'s values.  The return type of the anonymous function (`() => []`) thus cannot be inferred, and since it returns an empty list with no explicit type parameter, the `List`'s element type also cannot be inferred.  The anonymous function therefore is compiled as a `Function` that returns a `List<dynamic>`.

Meanwhile, `exampleMap`'s *runtime* type is actually a `HashMap<String, List<Foo>>`.  When you execute the code, `putIfAbsent` will fail due to the inability to safely add a `List<dynamic>` where a `List<Foo>` is expected.

If you fix your original declaration to use `var`, then your `putIfAbsent` call should work without any additional changes.  If you actually do want `exampleMap`'s static type to be `HashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`, then you alternatively could change your `putIfAbsent` call to provide an explicit type for the empty `List`: `exampleMap.putIfAbsent('bar', () => <Foo>[])`.

I'll also point out that if you don't allow `null` values in your `Map`, I much prefer using `??=` over `putIfAbsent`:

```dart
var exampleMap = HashMap<String, List<Foo>>();
exampleMap['bar'] ??= [];
```