# How to have a list where the elements are the same generic type but with different generic values in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I am working on an app using Dart and Flutter. The code below is a simplified and isolated version of the real problem I am running into.

I would like to make a list that holds only items of the generic class X.  X has two generic values: Y and Z.  I would like the elements in the list to have different values for Y and Z.  So `[X<Y1, Z1>, X<Y2, Z2>]` but I keep getting this exception:

> "_TypeError (type '(DateFilter, Question) => bool' is not a subtype of
> type '(dynamic, dynamic) => bool')"

I haven't been able to figure out how to add extra generic type annotations to get it to work.

```
void main() {
  List<Foo> list = [
    Foo(arg: "hello", func: func1),
    Foo(arg: 100, func: func2),
  ];
}

bool func1(Bar bar) {
  return true;
}

bool func2(Bar bar) {
  return false;
}

class Foo<T, U> {
  final T arg;
  final bool Function(U) func;

  const Foo({
    required this.arg,
    required this.func
  });
}

class Bar {
  final String text;

  const Bar({
    required this.text
  });
}
```

Comment: When you do: `List<Foo> list = [Foo(...)]`, you are declaring `list` to be of type `List<Foo>`, which is shorthand for `List<Foo<dynamic, dynamic>>`.  The elements of the right-hand-side then are inferred to be `Foo<dynamic, dynamic>` and therefore expect `func` callbacks that take `dynamic` arguments.  If you omit the explicit declaration then the elements will be inferred to be `Foo<String, Bar>` and `Foo<int, Bar>` (and then `list` will be inferred to be `List<Foo<Object, Bar>>`.  This is why omitting explicit type declarations can be safer.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61807738/.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you for the answer.  It helped some but I am still struggling with this.  As I mentioned in a comment to the answer from Dhafin Rayhan, I forgot that the func property on the Foo type needs to also take an argument of type T.  Should I create a new question with this added detail?  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @jamesdlin could you provide the code for one of the functions?

Comment: Sorry, my earlier remark about making `func1` and `func2` generic was not quite right.  Simply using `bool func1<T>(Bar bar, T x) { return true; }` and using `Foo(..., func: func1)` will cause `func1` to be inferred as `func1<dynamic>`.  While that will compile and run, it's not what you intend (defeating the point of making `func1` generic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do: `List<Foo> list = [Foo(...)]`, you are declaring `list` to be of type `List<Foo>`, which is shorthand for `List<Foo<dynamic, dynamic>>`.  Inference then flows from left-to-right: the elements of the right-hand-side then are inferred to be `Foo<dynamic, dynamic>` and therefore expect `func` callbacks that take `dynamic` arguments.

If you instead omit the explicit declaration then the elements will be inferred to be `Foo<String, Bar>` and `Foo<int, Bar>`, and inference will flow from right-to-left, causing `list` to be inferred to be `List<Foo<Object, Bar>>`. (This is why omitting explicit type declarations can be safer.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61807738/.)

Regarding your comments about wanting to make `func1` and `func2` take additional `T` arguments: you could make `func1` and `func2` generic on `T`.  For example:

```dart
bool func1<T>(Bar bar, T x) {
  return true;
}
```

However, while it's tempting to do only that (and that's what I initially tried), it doesn't quite do what's intended.  The inference flow doesn't allow `func1<T>` to be inferred from the sibling argument to `Foo`. (There's *some* support for inferring argument types from sibling arguments, but there are limitations.  See https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/731.)

Explicitly specifying a type (e.g. `Foo('hello', func: func1<String>)`) is also problematic if you attempt to invoke the callback functions through `list`.  That is, something like:

```dart
void main() {
  var list = [
    Foo(arg: "hello", func: func1<String>),
    Foo(arg: 100, func: func2<int>),
  ];
  
  var bar = Bar(text: 'hi');
  
  for (var i in list) {
    i.func(bar, i.arg); // ERROR
  }
}
```

will fail at runtime:

> ```
> Error: TypeError: Closure 'func1' with <String>: type '(Bar, String) => bool' is not a subtype of type '(Bar, Object) => bool'
> ```

`list` is `List<Foo<Object, Bar>>`, `i` has a static type of `Foo<Object, Bar>`, and therefore `i.func(bar, i.arg)` expects to invoke a `Function(Bar, Object)` but instead gets a `Function(Bar, String)`, [which isn't substitutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61966636/). (Furthermore, `i.arg` is only statically known to be an `Object`.)

If you aren't invoking the `Foo.func` methods directly through `list` (which inherently loses static type information), then it's not a problem.  For example, you could do:

```dart
void main() {
  var list = [
    Foo(arg: "hello", func: func1<String>),
    Foo(arg: 100, func: func2<int>),
  ];

  var bar = Bar(text: 'hi');

  for (var i in list) {
    i.execute(bar);
  }
}

bool func1<T>(Bar bar, T x) {
  print('func1<$T>(Bar(${bar.text}), $x)');
  return true;
}

bool func2<T>(Bar bar, T x) {
  print('func2<$T>(Bar(${bar.text}), $x)');
  return false;
}

class Foo<T, U> {
  final T arg;
  final bool Function(U, T) func;

  bool execute(U u) => func(u, arg);

  const Foo({required this.arg, required this.func});
}

class Bar {
  final String text;

  const Bar({required this.text});
}
```

which outputs:

```
func1<String>(Bar(hi), hello)
func2<int>(Bar(hi), 100)
```

showing that `func1` and `func2` are properly typed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by jamesdlin, `List<Foo>` is actually `List<Foo<dynamic, dynamic>>`. Now that you already have a "contract" that the items of `list` will have the `Foo<dynamic, dynamic>` type, you also make a "contract" that the function given to its `func` property will accept a `dynamic` as its parameter.

Now here's an example:

```dart
void main() {
  List<Foo> list = [
    Foo(arg: "hello", func: func1), // Analyzer complains here
    Foo(arg: 100, func: func2), // And here
  ];

  final foo1 = list[0];
  dynamic baz = 5;
  final result = foo1.func(baz);
}

bool func1(Bar bar) {
  // Doing Bar specific actions...
  if (bar.text == 'Hello') return false;

  return true;
}
```

As you can see, calling `foo1.func(baz)` should be no problem, because `foo1` is a `Foo` and as we know we made contract the its `func` property will accept a `dynamic` as its parameter. But in fact, the `func` that we passed to the `foo1` object is a `bool Function(Bar)`, which may contains `Bar` specific code that is not applicable to other types. That is why, the Dart analyzer has complained from the moment you passed a `bool Function(Bar)` to the `func` parameter which is a `bool Function(dynamic)`.

---

There is also a "**consumer** and **producer**" concept in substituting types, which defines when a subtype can be replaced by a supertype and when a supertype can be replaced by a subtype.

See: [Substituting types](https://dart.dev/language/type-system#substituting-types)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am confused though.  Are you explaining why this isn't possible in Dart? I don't see or understand a solution in what you wrote.  I also realized I need an extra level of complexity to make this toy problem the same as my real problem:  the func property of Foo needs to also except a parameter of type T: "final bool Function(U, T) func;"

Comment: There is no solution to your requirements. It is not only impossible in Dart, but also logically wrong, as explained in my answer. The only way out is to deal with `func1` and `func2` themselves and make them generic functions or even accepting dynamic and have type checking inside

Comment: Ok, the type checking option was my fallback.  Thank you for the help